# Make an unselectable option in html select

Tags: html, select

is there a way to create a select element, but in the middle of the option itens, an option that cant be selected? It would work like a label.

```
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>

<!--this one cant be selected -->
 <option value="">title</option>

 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you don’t want to use `optgroup`?

Comment: @t.niese I just checked about optgroup thanks to you, that is perfect for me! Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may used `disabled` attribute.
This attribute is a `boolean` attribute.

When present, it specifies that an option should be `disabled`.

A `disabled` option is unusable and un-clickable.

```html
<select>
 <option value="A">A</option>
 <option value="B">B</option>
 <option value="C">C</option>

<!--this option cant be selected -->
 <option value="" disabled>title</option>

 <option value="D">D</option>
 <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `disabled` property on the `<option>` element.

```html
    <select>
     <option value="A">A</option>
     <option value="B">B</option>
     <option value="C">C</option>
     <option value="" disabled="disabled">title</option><!--this one can't be selected -->
     <option value="D">D</option>
     <option value="E" disabled>E</option><!-- nor this one -->
    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a disabled attribute like this

```
<select>
    <option value="A">A</option>
    <option value="B">B</option>
    <option value="C">C</option>

    <!--this one cant be selected -->
    <option value="" disabled>title</option>

    <option value="D">D</option>
    <option value="E">E</option>
</select>
```